where did the graphical calendar disappear from qml qt 5, why is it not in qt6.7?
where did the graphical calendar like this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-calendar.html
How to create a similar calendar in qml qt 6.7


What about this?

This is a singletone class or namespace, but isn't a graphical component

Check CalendarModel and MonthGrid

@xzxolop If you carefully read that page, it also refers to the views that are based on it, specifically MonthGrid.
